# 218TB XFS LVM filesystem. 144TB Free. Error message "No Free Space Left on Device"

Tags: lvm, disk-usage, raid, limit, xfs

I have a giant 218 TB RAID6, across LVM.  It is actually 2 separate RAID6s joined together through LVM to form one giant RAID6.  `df -h` shows all space was available, and I mounted to `/share`.

I wanted to test that all of the 218 TB was actually usable, so I started running `fallocate -l 1TB` in a loop, and when it got to 75 TB it stated that the device was out of space.  Typing `df -h`, it showed that there was still 144 TB free on `/share`.

I looked this up and a lot of people recommended typing `df -i` to see if all the inode space was taken up, but only 1% used.

Is there a hidden limitation to how much space can actually be allotted to one RAID6?  Or is it because I have it configured with LVM?

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: If your issue is like this one https://www.centos.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=21766 , you may need to mount with the `-o inode64` option.

Comment: Yes, I am using LVM2.

Comment: That issue looks similar to what I am experiencing, but when I try to mount with the inode64 option and create files, my terminal kinda freezes, waiting for the process to complete, and then it spits out kernel errors.

Comment: I tried to reproduce your issue using a 218T loop device in tmpfs. The first time I tried I thought I could reproduce it (fallocate stopped after the 114th 1TB file). Subsequent tries it happily fallocates 217+ TB files. Even works with `inode32`. Never could reproduce why it didn't work the first time though and now I'm unsure if I imagined it... ;)

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure if this is the one-and-done solution, but it worked for me.  I had to create my "LVM" with striping options.

```
lvcreate -L 217T -i2 -I64 -n lv_share VolGroup
```

See [4.4.2. Creating Striped Volumes](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Logical_Volume_Manager_Administration/LV_stripecreate.html).

Then I had to mount it with the `-o inode64` option, as Mark mentioned.

See [8.2. Mounting an XFS File System](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/6/html/Storage_Administration_Guide/xfsmounting.html).

Comment: Isn't `inode64` the default?

Comment: @frostschutz apparently not, cf. note about it in `mount(8)`